# Kibana dashboard - error saving to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have a logstash-elasticsearch-kibana local setup and I have a problem when it comes to save Kibana dashboards.
Selecting the "**Save**" option I get the following error: "**Save failed Dashboard could not be saved to Elasicsearch**"
I'm using the logstash dashboard that comes with Kibana and after some modifications I tried to save it getting this error.

As far as I understand dashboards loaded from templates (json files located in kibana3/app/dashboards) cannot be saved to Elasticsearch (as stated in [kibana templates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/kibana/current/templated-and-scripted-dashboards.html)). But I haven't been able to figure out how to create a new dashboard for logstash and save it to Elasticsearch, nor find instructions to do that. I would like to have different dashboards and be able to modify them and load them as needed.

I have exported the dashboard schema and successfully load it back, which works as far as saving a dashboard after all customization is done. But I would prefer to save them to elasticsearch rather than to template files.

Communication between ES and Kibana works fine (no errors show up in logs and information is retrieved and showed in Kibana).

Someone who could tell me what I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if the index kibana-int is available in elasticsearch?  This should be created to store the dashboards.

Comment: There's no kibana-int index present (I'm looking at elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/ folder and I only have one index of a pervious logstash test). Should kibana-int be created automatically? I also tried adding kibana-int index manually but I still get the same error.

Comment: Strang, can you post the command you try to execute to create the index?

Comment: I'm using **"curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/kibana-int/'"** and I see the index created with **"localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v"**.
Index auto-creation is enabled by default, right? shouldn't this index be created automatically?

Comment: Yes you are right they should be created by default. Maybe try to reproduce using clean elasticsearch/kibana?

Answer (score 0):

I got the error when I had a '/' (slash) in the name of the dashboard. Changing this to '-' solved the problem. See the following issue on GitHub: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/837

Comment: Thanks Jens, but that was not the issue (no slashes in my dashboard's name). I still have to reproduce the problem with a clean setup. For the moment I export the dashboards and access them at http://localhost/#/dashboard/file/dashboardname.json